# How do I fix an uneven cement floor prior to hard wood flooring install?

Tags: repair, concrete, floor

I have recently ripped up carpet and padding on a cement floor for a sixth floor condo unit. I plan on installing 3/4" Bella, 3' wide flooring on it. The problem is that there is a ridge, about 1/8", running the length of the room in the cement floor that will buckle the planks if left unaddressed.

What (if any) methods are there for smoothing this ridge?

**Edit: I believe the floors are precast concrete slabs and looks like one slab is a little off level, or it settled a bit, thus this ridge.
Maybe another way to ask this - Is there a way to compensate for the slight off levelness as it runs about 20'? The rest of the floor slabs are level with each other.**

Comment: How high is the ridge?

Comment: about 1/8" but it runs the length of the room, in the direction the wood will be layed out. It will be just enough to seperate the seams of the planks in that area.

Comment: I added a detail that may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picture might be helpful but I think you have two options:

1) Grind down the ridge.  This will be messy and create lots of dust

2) Use a self-leveling concrete mix.  This is a special mix that starts off almost like water, levels itself and sets relatively quickly. Follow the directions carefuly as usually you have to work with it pretty fast from the time you mix to the time you pour.  It will flow into any cracks and holes so make sure that any of these that might cause problems with another floor below you are sealed before you start.

Comment: +1 for your answer. I have used self level before, but just in a small area. This would be about 20' long by 5' wide. thats a boat load of mixing and as I remember it ain't cheap, so the cost be be near the price of the flooring. I might look into the grinding down. Is there a specific tool I should ask for at the rent a center?

Comment: Not so much as you think.  You only need 1/8" depth coverage.  A 40lb bag of HENRY Level Pro covers 43 sq ft at 1/8 in.  That's 3 bags - call it $120.  Your alternative - grinding a 20' ridge - that's going to be very, VERY messy and very hard to get even.

Comment: I can accept that! Great Advice on the self leveler! and thanks Evil G for backing it up with your comments.

Comment: You could try to rent a floor grinder and the vacuum attachment. That would cut down on the mess.